# WordPress: How to set a specific role based on another advanced custom field

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress application and we have added a custom field via the advanced custom fields plugin.

This is working well!

We need to set a specific role though based on the Registration Pin that we have added via the advanced custom fields plugin.

We tried to update the code in users.php, within the `function wp_insert_user( $userdata ) {` method, but we have failed.

Here is the code we tried to set:

```
debug_to_console('hey cindyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
    debug_to_console($userdata);
    if ( isset( $userdata['role'] ) ) {
        $user->set_role( $userdata['role'] );
    } elseif ( ! $update ) {
        if ($userdata['registration_pin'] == 9742)
        {
            $user->set_role('club_member');
        }
        else if ($userdata['registration_pin'] == 9744) {
            $user->set_role('new_member');
        }
        else{
            $user->set_role( get_option( 'default_role' ) );
        }
        //$user->set_role( get_option( 'default_role' ) );
        //      $user->set_role('new_member');
        //  $user->set_role('club_member');
    }
```

In this code, it passes the 2 if statements and goes directly to the else which sets the 'default role'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a valid answer:

```
    // validate the registration pin is 9999
    if ($field['_name'] === 'registration_pin')
    {
        if ($value !== "9999")
        {
            $message = "Registration pin is incorrect.";
            $valid   = false;
        }
    }
```

Full code on function:

```
function acf_validate_value( $value, $field, $input ) {

    // vars
    $valid   = true;
    $message = sprintf( __( '%s value is required', 'acf' ), $field['label'] );

    // valid
    if ( $field['required'] ) {

        // valid is set to false if the value is empty, but allow 0 as a valid value
        if ( empty( $value ) && ! is_numeric( $value ) ) {

            $valid = false;

        }
    }

    /**
    *  Filters whether the value is valid.
    *
    *  @date    28/09/13
    *  @since   5.0.0
    *
    *  @param   bool $valid The valid status. Return a string to display a custom error message.
    *  @param   mixed $value The value.
    *  @param   array $field The field array.
    *  @param   string $input The input element's name attribute.
    */
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/type={$field['type']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/name={$field['_name']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( "acf/validate_value/key={$field['key']}", $valid, $value, $field, $input );
    $valid = apply_filters( 'acf/validate_value', $valid, $value, $field, $input );

    // validate the registration pin is 9999
    if ($field['_name'] === 'registration_pin')
    {
        if ($value !== "9999")
        {
            $message = "Registration pin is incorrect.";
            $valid   = false;
        }
    }

    // allow $valid to be a custom error message
    if ( ! empty( $valid ) && is_string( $valid ) ) {

        $message = $valid;
        $valid   = false;

    }

    if ( ! $valid ) {

        acf_add_validation_error( $input, $message );
        return false;

    }

    // return
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way it would pass those two "if statements" would be because either $userdata['registration_pin'] is not equal to 9742 or 9744, or $userdata['registration_pin'] doesn't exist in the $userdata

I am sure the problem is $userdata['registration_pin'] doesn't exist, ACF wouldn't save a custom field in your userdata like that... by default custom fields from ACF are saved in the user_meta table

You should be able to access the registration key with this:

```
$registration_key = get_user_meta($user_id, 'registration_key', true);
```